# How to move a TeXLive installation from a Linux 32 bit machine to another one

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu, linux, offline

Two Linux machines with the same Linux OS version and architecture (32 bit) are given.

Is there an easy way to just copy some files and folders from the first Machine to the second-one in order to use TeXlive on the second machine?

Which files and folders should be copied?

This question is related to [Copying a TeXLive installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28113/) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16530/
The answers provided there, do not specify which explicit files or folder should be moved/copied.

**Motivation**:
According to [How to install texlive from DVD onto a 32bit linux machine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496513/how-to-install-texlive-from-dvd-onto-a-32bit-linux-machine) an offline installation of TeXLive from a DVD or an ISO image is not possible. Hence the only way to go is an online installation. But an online installation, depending on internet and network situations, is time-consuming and is less bandwidth-friendly. Hence, an offline installation once an online installation is completed is perhaps desirable.

**Other case use**: Sometimes one would like to re-install Linux, it would be helpful if one could copy TeXLive files and folders to a USB key, and then paste them once the OS is re-installed.

Comment: If you installed the tug version just  copy /usr/local/texlive/2020 or whatever to the new machine, everything is in that one place. If you installed the linux system package managed version it's possibly simpler to just install it the same way on the new machine as otherwise you may confuse the package manager there as it won't know tex is installed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Isn't `~/.texlive2021` necessary? Can the the executables be recognized just by copying  `/usr/local/texlive/2020`?

Comment: No that's per user local data, it'll get made for each user if needed whether or not you copy. You can copy if you want, may save a bit of time initially makeing a luatex cache or whatever but I wouldn't bother normally.